# can not launch Spyder in windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have downloaded Anaconda navigator 2019.07. the spyder app has shown but can not launch when I clicked.

I tried to reinstall the Anaconda installer but no improve. the Anaconda navigator also did not show Spyder IDE.

I expect the Spyder should Run without any issue.

It has shown an error mentioned below.
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets'